# How can I use Julmars ITAPI3 in C# Correctly?

Tags: c#, call, modem, tapi

I programming a TAPI application in C#.  I used the ITAPI3 Wrapper from Julmar.  Now I can make the software make calls.  However the array that holds calls that are there is not filling.  I am not sure if this is a problem inside of the wrapper itself or if I am doing something wrong.  When I used TAPI Soft phone from julmar, which is a C++ Tapi Application, it does see calls correctly and I can answer them.  Its just using the wrapper it does not seem to see calls and the OnNewCall event does not fire.

Even Julmar's samples have not worked correctly for me using ITAPI3.

Anyone have any issues like this?
Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0):

I'm working with TAPI in C# too. Now, I'm using ATAPI by julmar. This is the link. http://atapi.codeplex.com/

Comment: [ATAPI](https://github.com/markjulmar/atapi/) is only for 2.x and not 3.x